# How to install YmCrypt.ocx ON Delphi 6

Tags: delphi, vb6, delphi-6

I have YmCrypt.ocx...
On VB6 ...when I import the file, so it will make an object,, So I can paste on the form, and I can use it...But On Delphi6, why Can I not do like as on vb6? It can create an unit, but it dont make an object.
So My question is...

1. Can I use YmCrypt.ocx on Delphi6?
2. If can, please explain to me. I'm very happy, if there is a code that can load the ocx at run time.

```
LIBID_YMCrypt_bl0sh: TGUID = '{1382B389-9A89-48C1-B056-7BECA8BD9FA2}';
  IID__YMC: TGUID = '{D2E65791-DA25-44E4-B9CB-27DE41BC4E1B}';
  DIID___YMC: TGUID = '{D39DF4F9-E0F3-417C-9700-6E78FD2AD041}';
  CLASS_YMC: TGUID = '{B2AFE6EC-D3A6-4445-B515-532C9E020380}';
```

I had tried to call it , like this :

```
VAR
    ObjTokenYM: YMC;
begin
    ObjTokenYM:=CreateComObject(CLASS_YMC) as YMC;
```

when I run the code, There is no error... But I'm not sure if this can be used or not ?
Because when i try to call a method of the class, like this:

```
VAR
    ObjTokenYM: YMC;
begin
    ObjTokenYM:=CreateComObject(CLASS_YMC) as YMC;
    ObjTokenYM.About;
```

So...I get an error message..."Non-modal forms cannot be displayed in this host application from an ActiveX DLL, ActiveX Control, or Property page ..."

Comment: Please explain what you have done, and how it fails.

Comment: When I try to install/import it...so it can not make an on object...Unlike mswinsck.OCX, will immediately make an object / component

Comment: I've no idea what that means. You need to describe precisely what steps you are taking. I know English is not your first language, but we have to live with that. We need more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your patience on my English is bad. May I know your email? or how do I send the ocx file, so you can try it yourself, and will know where that would be the problem?

Comment: No, we don't do that here. You should try to improve the question.

Comment: The point is, when the ocx files are imported into Delphi6, and do not form an object / component, does the ocx mean not support on Delphi6?